# Unable to import drop-down attribute options with product import Magento2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, import-products

1. I have created an attribute  Model with type dropdown and added options values.
2. Assign the value to some products and export the CSV and it is working fine.
3. Add some more products and try to import then I found that it imports all the information and ignores the dropdown attribute value.

Please Help if anyone faced this issue in magento2.

Comment: Are you trying to import the csv with the attribute value or label?

Comment: @AlanZavagli , IT is working now.  I add attributes code as diff columns